# Unble to call JavaScript method from PrimeFacec CommandButton

Tags: javascript, primefaces, jsf-2.2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function checkUncheckWOClosure()
        {                           
            if(woTypeAutoWOClosure.isChecked() == true)
                {
                woTypeAutoActClosure.check();
                }
            else
                {
                woTypeAutoActClosure.uncheck();
                }
        }
      </script> 

<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="workOrderTypeAutoActClosure" 
                                     value="#{workOrderTypeCrud.instance.autoActClosure}" widgetVar="woTypeAutoActClosure">
 </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>                
 <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="workOrderTypeAutoWOClosure"
                                     value="#{workOrderTypeCrud.instance.autoWOClosure}" widgetVar="woTypeAutoWOClosure" onclick="checkUncheckWOClosure()">                                          
  </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

Actually I want to auto-check the first checkbox when i click on 2nd check box.and Uncheck the first checkbox when I uncheck the 2nd check box.

Comment: Any errors in your browser console? Try to change this line as follows: `if(woTypeAutoWOClosure.checked() == true)`

Comment: Previously it was working fine but when I upgraded primefaces version from 3.5 to 6.0 then it's not working.

Comment: @chaeschuechli, Sorry it's not working.

Comment: Please provide version info directly with your question next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has some errors:

1. `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox />` does not have a *onclick* attribute. An alternative may be *onchange* attribute:

```xml
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox
    id="workOrderTypeAutoWOClosure"
    value="#{workOrderTypeCrud.instance.autoWOClosure}"
    widgetVar="woTypeAutoWOClosure"
    onchange="checkUncheckWOClosure();">
/>
```

2. Simply refering a component by *widgetVar* attribute value from JS does not work. You have to use `PF('<widgetVar>')`:

```js
function checkUncheckWOClosure() {                           
    if(PF('woTypeAutoWOClosure').isChecked() == true) {
        PF('woTypeAutoActClosure').check();
    } else {
        PF('woTypeAutoActClosure').uncheck();
    }
}
```

Comment: @kamal You are welcome. So may i ask you to accept this as answer.